# Rubymine can not recognize path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, rubymine-7

Even for the latest version of Rubymine(7.1), it could not recognise well some paths, for example:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Hello!', welcome_say_hello_path %></p>
```

Here, welcome_say_hello_path is defined in routes.rb:

```
get 'welcome/say_hello' => 'schools#search'
```

Is there anyone has the same problem?

Comment: is that rubymine's fault if its not a named route?

Comment: Sometimes, even you have had a named route, Rubymine still can not know it. For example, I have this: get 'welcome/say_hello' => 'schools#search',:as => 'test', and try to use in view file: <p><%= link_to 'Hello!', test_path %></p>